# Architectural Missmatch Exception Occurs while connecting to Remote Tally using ODBC in dotnet Winforms

Tags: .net, winforms, odbc, tally

Im Trying to Connect to Tally Prime Using ODBC in dotnet winforms .I Faced an exception While Connecting to a tally with ip address which is in another system in my same network .The Error i faced is Architectural Missmatch Error .

```
source = "SERVER="+ props.GetValueOrDefault("tally.hostname") +";DSN=TallyODBC64_9000;PORT=" + props.GetValueOrDefault("tally.port") + ";DRIVER=Tally ODBC Driver;" ;
var  con = new OdbcConnection(source);
 con.Open();
```

this is my code .

```
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application'
```

this is the exception i faced on** con.Open();**

How Can I Fix This

while i am using localhost it connects to my local tally without any error..
and if im using my ip addess it also connects..But if i use another ip address of a system in my same location that have tally , it couldn't connect..

i have build my application as x64 and x86 formats and tested ..but same result
How Can I Fix This Problem.